# Visual Studio Compiling & Detecting Operater Overloading While g++ doesn't

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013, g++

I have a house class. I initialize a new house element with `house house;` then I pass data into it and then I cout it:

```
cout << house;
```

Couting house works just fine in Visual Studio, but for some reason, I receive this error when I try to compile with g++:

```
main.cpp:19:57: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ (operand types are ‘std::basic_ostream<char>::__ostream_type {aka std::basic_ostream<char>}’ and ‘house’)
cout << "\nnext house to be visited:" << endl << endl << house << endl;
```

Even though I very clearly have this in one of my header files:

```
friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, house);
```

Any feedback you can give would be greatly appreciated, as I can see no reason for g++ not being able to see my operator overloading function.

Edit: Here's my operator overloading function:

```
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house& house)
{
    out << "Address: " << house.getAddress() << std::endl
        << "Square Feet: " << house.getSqrFt() << std::endl
        << "Bedrooms: " << +house.getBedrooms() << std::endl
        << "Bathrooms: " << house.getBathrooms() << std::endl
        << "Description: " << house.getDescription() << std::endl;
    return out;
}
```

And here's my house class:

```
#ifndef HOUSE
#define HOUSE
class house
{
public:
    house();
    house(const char[], const unsigned short& sqrFt, const unsigned char& bedrooms, const float& bathrooms, const char[]);
    house(house & obj);
    house(house *& obj);
    ~house();
    char * getAddress() const;
    unsigned short getSqrFt() const;
    unsigned char getBedrooms() const;
    float getBathrooms() const;
    char * getDescription() const;
    void setAddress(const char address[]);
    void setSqrFt(const unsigned short& sqrFt);
    void setBedrooms(const unsigned char& bedrooms);
    void setBathrooms(const float& bathrooms);
    void setDescription(const char description[]);
    void setEqual(house &, house*);
private:
    char * address;
    unsigned short sqrFt;
    unsigned char bedrooms;
    float bathrooms;
    char * description;
};
#endif
```

And here's my queue class which contains the declaration of my operator overloading function:

```
#ifndef QUEUE
#define QUEUE
#include <ostream>
#include "house.h"

class queue
{
public:
    queue();
    queue(queue & obj);
    ~queue();
    void enqueue(house *& item);
    bool dequeue(house & item);
    void print() const;
    void readIn(const char []);
private:
    struct node
    {
        node();
        house* item;
        node * next;
    }; 
    node * head;
    node * tail;
    void getLine(std::ifstream&, char key[]);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const char[]);
    //friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, house *&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house&);
};
#endif
```

Comment: Strange, I can't see `friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, house);` inside the declaration of class `house`

Comment: Change the class name to House or your variable name to ahouse but don't use the same name for class and variable name.

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki It's declared in a separate list class. Should I include that?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Is the declaration in `queue` the *only* declaration for `operator<<(ostream&, const house&)`?

Comment: @Barry Yes, then it's constructed in my queue.cpp file.

Comment: I highly recommend, for easy debugging and maintenance, to choose different names for variables and structures.  For example, use `struct House` and `House my_house;` for variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're declaring your `operator<<` for `house` in the wrong class:

```
class queue
{
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house&);
};
```

When you declare a friend operator in a class `X`, lookup for that operator only succeeds when we look for `X`. With this declaration, we will only find `operator<<(std::ostream&, const house&)` when we look up a `queue` - but that is impossible, since none of the arguments is a `queue` and so we'd never try to look it up with one.

You need to move your declaration to the correct class:

```
class house {
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, const house&);
};
```

Comment: I am not sure that your answer is correct.  You wrote "When you declare a friend operator in a class `X`, lookup for that operator only succeeds when we look for `X`." However, per the spec "\[friend\] declarations give special access rights to the friends, but they do not make the nominated friends members of the befriending class."  Furthermore, taking a look at "Operators in expressions" \[over.match.oper\], I am not seeing how declaring a function as a friend would impact operator overload resolution.  Why is `queue` the "wrong class"?  It's unusual and probably not intended, but wrong?

Comment: @DanielTrebbien [namespace.memdef] talks about name lookup for friend functions.